# Is it necessary to specify directory when using appendFileSync?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm going through some of the nodejs documentation and starting to familiarize myself with some of the more basic functions. Specifically looking at appendFileSync function.

When trying to append a file, is it necessary to specify the directory? I don't recall this being a requirement in previous versions of Node but it seems when the directory is not specified, a new file is created in the root instead of appending the file.

I'm just trying to append a basic txt file, with this it creates a new file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFileSync('notes.txt', 'Changing the text with appendFileSync');
```

However, when specifying the directory, it appends the file just fine making me think this is required:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFileSync('./nodejs/notes-app/notes.txt', ' Colin, changed the 
text with appendFileSync', function (err) {
if (err) throw err; console.log('Notes updated');
});
```

Node -v 12.13.0

NPM -v 6.12.0

Comment: So it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all `fs` operations that take a file path, if you don't specify any sort an absolute path, then the path you do specify is combined with the current working directory.  In a nodejs program, the default current working directory (if you don't change it programmatically) is taken from the environment in which you started the node program.

If want to control the path directly without regard to the current working directory, then specify an absolute path.

This is what the [`fs` module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths) says about file paths:

> String form paths are interpreted as UTF-8 character sequences identifying the absolute or relative filename. Relative paths will be resolved relative to the current working directory as specified by process.cwd().

Note: For some situations, a developer wants to access the file system relative to the installation of the module that is running.  That is typically done by building a path that is relative to `__dirname` which is the location of the current module like this.

```
path.join(__dirname, "somefile.txt");
```

Of course, you can always specific a full path name starting from root if you want.